# After installing wheel and httplib2 library I cannot import httplib2 in my code

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, httplib2

What is my mistake?

1. Opened command line and installed

```
C:\Users\Caro Schor>pip install httplib2
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2 in c:\users\caro schor\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (0.17.3)

Could not build wheels for httplib2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.


Could not install the wheel and could not import httplib2.
```

2. Then I installed

```
C:\Users\Caro Schor>python -m pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
  WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Caro Schor\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed wheel-0.34.2
```

However, I still can not import the httplib2 library.

Would need a detailed description of what I need to do differently since I am a beginner with Python.

Comment: What is the ouput if you try again `pip install httplib2` ?

Comment: `pip install httplib2 --force-reinstall`